# Percentages in height and width of ZingChart do not work accordingly

Tags: height, width, zingchart

Whenever I am setting height and width of ZingChart in percentage, so that it's compatible with all screen sizes, it has no effect. 
Example: If I set 1% height and 1% width, nothing as such happens.
I am changing height and width as:

```
zingchart.render({ 
id : 'myChart', 
data : myConfig, 
height: '1%', 
width: '1%' 
 });
```

You can view the complete code here:
   http://jsfiddle.net/xbh2ap18/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ZingChart's height and width inherits from the parent container that you are attaching to. The actual chart is a child of myChart, so you will need to apply css to your container.

```js
zingchart.render({
  id  : 'myChart',
  data : {
    type:"line",
    series :[
      { values : [1,2,3,4] } 
    ]
  },
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%"
  
});
```

```css
html,body,#myChart{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```